# Load incomplete .dat file into R

Tags: r, ftp

My data comes from this [URL](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/asos-onemin/6406-2013/64060KFAT201312.dat) and has the following structure:

```
 93193KFAT FAT2013123016150015   NP [0000  ] 0.00              39999   29.791        
 93193KFAT FAT2013123016160016   NP [0000  ] 0.00              39999   29.791        
 93193KFAT FAT2013123016170017   NP [0000  ]                   39999   29.791        
 93193KFAT FAT2013123016170017   NP [0000  ] 0.00              39999   29.791
```

So if you see this:

1. the data is separated by blank spaces,
2. there are some column entries missing (ie. the 0.00 in row 3).

When I load this into R it gives me the error that:

```
 Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :   
 line 377 did not have 12 elements
```

How do you fix this? So that I can open this from the URL directly without any problems?

Thank you!

```
 > read.fwf(ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/asos-onemin/6406-2013/64060KFAT201312.dat)
 Error: unexpected '/' in "read.fwf(ftp:/"
 trying URL 'ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/asos-onemin/6406-    2013/64060KFAT201312.dat'
 using Synchronous WinInet calls
 Error in download.file(url, downloadPath) : 
 cannot open URL 'ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/asos-onemin/6406-2013/64060KFAT201312.dat'
 In addition: Warning message:
 In download.file(url, downloadPath) : InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
 Error in download.file(url, downloadPath) : unsupported URL scheme
```

1) Try url("....). I get the error:

```
 Error in url("ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/asos-onemin/6406-2013/64060KFAT201312.dat") : 
   unsupported URL scheme
```

2) I tried using library(RCurl) and do: getURL("...). I get the error:

```
 Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
 In addition: Warning message:
 In file(file, "rt") :
   cannot open file  [... and R shows the data in the url ]
```

Comment: use `utils::read.fwf`

Comment: i want to read (and possible write) the dataset, I use the "Tools" Import Dataset from R Studio, but i dont think this is the best way

Comment: It's either a fwf format or a tab-separated format.

Comment: I tried using read.fwf, but I get the following error. I updated the question to include the error

Comment: It is documented to be fwf in the README file in the ftp directory which tells you to look at: http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/documentlibrary/tddoc/td6406.pdf  PLEASE read the help file for read.fwf. You absolutely need a width argument. You also absolutely need quotes around URLs. And you need to read `?connection` where teh `url` function is described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of this:

```
a <- read.fwf("ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/asos-onemin/6406-2013/64060KFAT201312.dat", 
              widths=c(9, 20, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7))
```

Comment: I get... Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection , is this because of the website?

Comment: Heh, must be on windows or something. Try this: a <- read.fwf(url("ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/asos-onemin/6406-2013/64060KFAT201312.dat"), 
              widths=c(9, 20, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7))

Comment: Nearly, your code works fantastic if I have the data saved. Let me update the question, I can't make the url work...